# Bootstrap Tabs - change background image of body

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tabs, background-image

Trying to change the background image of the page when a tab is pressed using bootstrap. I was able to change it to a specific image, but I want to pull the background image from the active tab id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided much detail in your question, so I am not fully certain of what you are trying to accomplish, but perhaps this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/2kDxD/

The approach here is to take the `href` attribute text from the navlist, slightly modify the text, 
and then add that modified text to the body as a CSS class. Then set the style rules 
you want for the body background, such as the background-image property, in the CSS classes.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myNav">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">  
<div id="home" class="tab-pane active">
  <p>home</p>
</div> 
<div id="profile" class="tab-pane">
  <p>profile</p>
</div> 
<div id="messages" class="tab-pane">
  <p>messages</p>
</div> 
<div id="settings" class="tab-pane">
  <p>settings</p>
</div> 
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown', function (e) {
    var bodyBgClass = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "") + "-BgBackground";
    $("body").removeClass().addClass(bodyBgClass);
    // what is the new class?
    console.log(bodyBgClass);
});

// make sure the initial page load activates the tabs
$(function () {
    $('#myNav a:first').tab('show');
});
```

**CSS**

```
/* add background image to styles as needed */
.home-BgBackground {
  background-color: blue; 
  color: #fff;
}
.profile-BgBackground {
  background-color: yellow; 
  color: #222;
}
.messages-BgBackground {
  background-color: orange; 
  color: #222;
}
.settings-BgBackground {
  background-color: pink; 
  color: #222;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the js code:

```
    $('li>a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
    var bodyBgClass = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "") + "-BgBackground";
    $("body").removeClass().addClass(bodyBgClass);
    // what is the new class?
    console.log(bodyBgClass);
```